# How to do an animated plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do an animation plot of 
x = (dataset of 1000 points)
y = (dataset of 1000 points)
plot(x,y)

big problem is these are datasets that i am trying to plot , or x,y coordinates as opposed to a function which I would know how to plot via an animation.

I tried to do frames in a for loop but it gave me dots and didn't join them in a line graph so I couldn't really watch the path being traced out.

code I used was

```
for i = 1:length(DATASET1)
pause(0.1)
plot(DATASET1(i),DATASET2(i))
draw on
end
```

Comment: What is the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: That's not a plot command.... You should edit the post (with the link just below the tags) to include all of the code that you have so far. You can format the code by clicking the `{}` button, pressing `CTRL-K` or by indenting it by 4 spaces

Comment: Thank you so so sorry for not doing that..

Comment: for some reason I cant put the code in that format on a comment. I can if I go to answer the question but I have to wait 8 hours before I can do that.. sorry I will try and include it in my question

Comment: It is preferred that you edit it into the question rather than post it in a comment :-) Well done fixing up your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you were close. Not sure `draw on` is any command though.

See if the code here inspires you to solve your case -

```
%// Sample x and y values assumed for demo.
x = 1:1000;
y = x.^2;

%// Plot starts here
figure,hold on

%// Set x and y limits of the plot
xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])
ylim([min(y(:)) max(y(:))])

%// Plot point by point
for k = 1:numel(x)
    plot(x(k),y(k),'-') %// Choose your own marker here

    %// MATLAB pauses for 0.001 sec before moving on to execue the next 
    %%// instruction and thus creating animation effect
    pause(0.001);     
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. for some reason it wouldnt do my plot I modified it setting x = DATASET1 and y = DATASET2 The axis are coming up but nothing is being drawn on them

Comment: The big problem is I can get 'dots' to be updated but it wont form a line graph for me to see the path that has been created

Comment: Add this after the loop exits - `plot(x,y,'-')`

Comment: @branny12000 Let me know if the code worked for you. I will update my solution accordingly.

Comment: Maybe that original "`draw on`" was intended to be [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html). That's generally needed to tell Matlab to flush the graphic event queue, and force it to draw your plot _now_. In your code you don't need `drawnow`, however, because it is called implicitly by `pause`.

Comment: Divakar!! Sorry for the delay!! For some reason your question slipped through the net! Yes your code worked beautifully thank you :)))

Comment: @branny12000 Welcome back!:) I don't know if you still need any help on this problem. In any case, just for the sake of fulfilling `SO` duties, if convenient accept the best of the lot!

Comment: Hi there how do I accept your answer? I cant see 'accept'

Comment: @branny12000 Oh! Well there must be a green colored checkmark right below the up-down voting buttons on the left side to each solution presented here. Clicking on the checkmark signals the "acceptance".

Comment: Hi there Divakar! I think it must be different on the mobile but I have managed to accept your answer on my PC :) Also I wanted to ask you a related problem. I am currently using your technique to animate a colour plot. However, the axis and colour limits keeps changing so the plot if one colour then another. Also The animation isnt smooth and loads of graphs. my code is;

Comment: i = 1;
j = 8;
for a= 1:OverallL
    cla(gca);
    hold on
colormap(jet)
figure(a)
P(a) = imagesc(xaxis,yaxis,OVERALL(i:j,:)); 
hold off
drawnow 
i = i+9;
j = i+8;
a = a+1;
end

Comment: @branny12000 To keep the axis the same, you can put axes limits with `xlim`  and `ylim`. To keep the colors the same , you need to play around with the third parameter to `imagesc`. To keep the animation smooth, I think you need to increase the number of plot points. Good luck and appreciate the acceptance! :)

Answer (score 37):

If what you want is for the plot to "grow" point by point: the easiest way is to create an empty plot and then update its `XData` and `YData` properties at each iteration:

```
h = plot(NaN,NaN); %// initiallize plot. Get a handle to graphic object
axis([min(DATASET1) max(DATASET1) min(DATASET2) max(DATASET2)]); %// freeze axes
%// to their final size, to prevent Matlab from rescaling them dynamically 
for ii = 1:length(DATASET1)
    pause(0.01)
    set(h, 'XData', DATASET1(1:ii), 'YData', DATASET2(1:ii));
    drawnow %// you can probably remove this line, as pause already calls drawnow
end
```

Here's an example<sup>1</sup> obtained with `DATASET1 = 1:100; DATASET2 = sin((1:100)/6);`

[image]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In case someone's interested, the figure is an animated gif which can be created by adding the following code (taken from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab)) within the loop, after the `drawnow` line:</sup>

```
  frame = getframe(1);
  im = frame2im(frame);
  [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
  if ii == 1;
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','Loopcount',inf);
  else
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');
  end
```

Comment: @Divakar Yep. I used [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab)

Comment: that's cool! just for sharing the animated gif you have my +1

Comment: @natan Thanks! I usually hate animated gifs for being too distracting... but I couldn't resist :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since R2014b, you can work with `annimatedline` object ([doc](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline.html) and [how-to](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline-object.html)) that is meant to handle animated graphs pretty well. Basically, the `annimatedline` object has a `addpoints` function that **adds new points to the line without having to redefine the existing points**, along with a `clearpoints` function that clears lines for more complex animations.

Here is an example:

```
h = animatedline;
axis([0,4*pi,-1,1])

x = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);
y = sin(x);
for k = 1:length(x)  
    addpoints(h,x(k),y(k));
    drawnow
end
```