# How do you animate a plot of two nx10 matrices?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I have an 870x10 matrix(y) and a 1X10(x) matrix. When i do plot(x,y) I get 870 lines which is is hard to read. Is there a way that I can see each line being plotted. In other words I want to see the first line being plotted then the second line and so on.

Comment: You could add a `hold on` to your figure and iterate through each line, adding one plot to the figure each time by calling `plot()` in your loop, possibly pausing in between. But that's not exactly an animation.

Comment: The problem is that when I do plot(x,y) it gives me all the lines at the same time. Using hold on would work if I had 870 1x10 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cc=hsv(870);
for current = 1: 870
   hold on;
   plot(x,y(current,:),'color',cc(current,:));
   pause();
end
```

You can try this. Use a colormap such as HSV to create a set of colors.

Comment: This works. Got any ideas on how to make the current line a different color because right now each line is the same color and the graph is still a little hard to read. Also is there a way to turn this into a video of GIF?

Comment: +1 // @JamesKl For generating an animated gif, check [this answer's footnote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689973/2586922) or [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab)

Comment: @Luis Mendo The answer helped I found out to make a GIF. All I needed to do is add a refresh time within the pause function.