# Plotting an array of plots without using for loop in octave / matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

How can I plot an array of plots all at once without using a `for loop`?

Example code below:

```
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc 

plot_array_x1=[-0.1732050807568878  -0.6767949192431123  -1.366025403784439
  0.1732050807568877  0.176794919243112  0.366025403784438
  6.123233995736766e-17  0.5000000000000001  1];

plot_array_y1=[-0.09999999999999995  0.186602540378444  0.366025403784439
  -0.1000000000000001  -0.6794228634059948  -1.366025403784439
  0.2  0.4928203230275509  0.9999999999999998];

for ii=1:3
  plot(plot_array_x1(ii,:),plot_array_y1(ii,:))
  hold on
end
```

The code produces the plot below but it requires me to use a `for loop` is it possible to avoid using a for loop?

[image: Plot]

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a `for` loop?

Comment: @excaza I will be animating various equations to see how they react when variables are changed and each part can have 100+ individual parts.  And using for loops several times with each having 100+ parts becomes very slow.  I'm almost looking for some way of plot to be vectorized (if that makes any sense)

Comment: The rest of your plotting code is more likely to be an issue than a `for` loop. If you're doing animation it's much faster to [update the `Axes`' `XData` and `YData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689973/2748311) than it is to repeatedly call `plot`, regardless of how "vectorized" the call is. I'm assuming similar properties exist in Octave.

Comment: @excaza Thanks I'll take a look at that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. First, transpose the arrays and then remove the loop.

```
plot_array_x1=[-0.1732050807568878  -0.6767949192431123  -1.366025403784439;
  0.1732050807568877  0.176794919243112  0.366025403784438;
  6.123233995736766e-17  0.5000000000000001  1].';

plot_array_y1=[-0.09999999999999995  0.186602540378444  0.366025403784439;
  -0.1000000000000001  -0.6794228634059948  -1.366025403784439;
  0.2  0.4928203230275509  0.9999999999999998].';

figure(1)
plot(plot_array_x1,plot_array_y1)
```

Comment: keep in mind that `.'` is transpose. `'` is the complex conjugate

Comment: thank you, @Andy. I made the correction on the answer