# How to efficiently animate plots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I wrote a simple code below for animating plots, but they tend to be rather computationally-intensive, taking entire seconds longer than intended:

```
function animplot(t,f,ymin,ymax,dt,num_iters)
h = plot(0,0); % set initial handle for first iteration
tic % start timer
for i=2:num_iters
    delete(h);
    h = plot(t,f(t-dt*i),'LineWidth',2,'color','b');
    axis([min(t) max(t) ymin ymax]); pause(1/num_iters)
end
toc % end timer, return time elapsed since 'tic'
end
```

Replacing `1/num_iters` with `dT = T / num_iters`, and setting `T = 1`, computation time for 1000 iterations is 6+ secs (rather than 1). [Sample animation](https://puu.sh/CKV6P/f58aad7556.mp4) for `t = 0:.01:2*pi; f = @(t)sin(t); dt = .05; num_iters = 1000`

Any more efficient methods of animating in this manner?

Comment: (Don't look at the accepted answer, but [the next one down, by Luis Mando](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689973/7328782).)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not a duplicate of linked question; mine asks to animate plot dynamics (updating entire plot w/ varying parameter), rather than plot generation (point-growth).

Comment: The answer is still the same. Look how the plot is updated in that answer. You can do the same thing. Pointing out the duplicate is meant to help you. I'm giving you an answer. Don't take it like an offense. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo No offense taken; indeed, upon closer inspection, the solution can apply per my inquiry - and is in fact significantly more efficient. Still, the code adaptation isn't too obvious - I'll hence post my solution code. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A significantly more efficient code, adapted per solution in [related inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688688/how-to-do-an-animated-plot-in-matlab/23689973#23689973):

```
function  animplot(t,f,ymin,ymax,dt,num_iters,T)
% ANIMPLOT(t,f,ymin,ymax,dt,num_iters) -- f must be defined w/ handle, 
% e.g. f = @(t)sin(t); default T = 5, num_iters = 500, dt = .05,
% (ymax - ymin) = 1.4*range.
switch nargin
    case 6; T = 5;
    case 5; T = 5; num_iters = 500;
    case 4; T = 5; num_iters = 500; dt = .05;
    case 2; T = 5; num_iters = 500; dt = .05; 
            ymin = 1.2*min(f(t)) - max(f(t))/5;
            ymax = 1.2*max(f(t)) - min(f(t))/5;
end

dT = T/num_iters; % set pause interval
h = plot(0,0,'LineWidth',2,'color','b'); % set initial handle
set(h, 'Xdata',t, 'Ydata', f(t));        % initialize curve plot
axis([min(t) max(t) ymin ymax]);
tic % start timer
for i=2:num_iters
    pause(dT)
    set(h, 'Ydata', f(t-dt*i))
end
toc % end timer, return time elapsed since 'tic'
end
```

Note: `num_iters` serves primarily as animation 'resolution'; higher comes at expense of greater deviation from set `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command: "set(h, 'Xdata',t, 'Ydata', f(t))" will be way more efficient than reusing the plot function on every loop iteration, and may be sufficient by itself to achieve the results you are looking for. For further improvement you can enable a variable frame rate. To do this, eliminate any "pause(dt)", get the time of the current loop iteration "t", evaluate your function for that time "f(t)" and set the plot x and y data to that. This will ensure that the animation is smooth does not take any longer than specified. You can also use this technique on data sets, not just functions, by using the "interp1(x,v,xq)" function to get a linear interpolation between data points.

Comment: A fine idea on replacing pause(dt), but may skip desireable plot frames with intensive functions - thanks for the input.