How to dynamically plot of every for loop iteration without blinking in MATLAB?
I am trying to to have a dynamically changing plot in a for loop using the following code:
clc, clear, close all
t = 0:0.00001:0.8;
iter = 1;
for f=0:0.5:50
    yu = sin(2*pi*f*t);
    yd = -1*[zeros(1,6666) yu];
    yd = yd(1:numel(yu));
    yu = yu(8150:end);  yd = yd(8150:end); 
    y(iter) = sum(abs(yu+yd))./(numel(yd));
    y2 = yu+yd;
    hp = subplot(211), plot(yu), hold on, plot(yd);title(num2str(f)) 
    ylim([-1.5 1.5])
    pause(0.1)
    drawnow,
    delete(hp);
    iter = iter+1;
    subplot(212), plot(y,'k'), hold on; drawnow, xlim([0 100]), ylim([0 2])
end

it seems to work, however, I have two problems:

the top subplot blinks in every iteration which I don't want. since I am going to create a movie of this for loop
I want to have f=0:0.5:50 as x-axis for the bottom subplot.

How can I change the code to solve these problems?

There's heaps of questions already related to this topic, I'm not sure what you mean by "blinking" or why that should impact your ability to create a movie (if you create the animation from capturing the plots directly rather than recording your screen), but you might want to update the plot data rather than replotting it from scratch, which would also be faster. Here is a good answer which covers both the line updating and saving the gif: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689973/3978545

@Wolfie gave you the best advice to improve your animation: do not create a subplot, then a plot, then delete the subplot and create a new one again inside the loop. Create the figure, with all the subplot, set their properties and limits, create the plots you are going to need (even empty if necessary) and save their handle, before the loop. Then in the loop you only update the YData (and XData if necessary) of the plots . That should produce a much smoother animation (recorded or not ...). The link in Wolfie's comment explains how to do that.
